# How to fix "Run time error '-2147417848(80010108) Method 'Range' of Object _ Worksheet' Failed" caused by code within a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code that calculate number automatically every time you edit a sheet. But somehow the code I wrote is not functioning properly that it gives a run-time error. I checked the cells and range but they are all valid and correct. All of the inputs and variables involved are simple integers (no more than 3 digits).

I just got a work assignment to automate some excel sheets at work and I just learned vba from ground up recently.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim A As Integer
Dim i As Byte

i = 5

For i = 5 To 12

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = "" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = 0 Then

            A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = A

    Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value * Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value _
            + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

It gives a run-time error

Comment: `Dim i As Byte`? Try `Dim i As Long` instead. Also, why is this a `Worksheet_Change()` event? Typically this is used when you have a specific `Target`, which you don't in this case.

Comment: @dwirony I tried Dim as Byte, Integer and Long. They don't make a difference. For the Worksheet_Change() event, my intention is to calculate column F automatically every time a new number goes into column D or E. I might need to add a lot more rows in the future so idk if I should add a specific Target.

Comment: @dwirony Also everytime I try to hit the "debug' when a error message pops out my excel will crash. This happens on more than 1 computers.

Comment: First start by putting `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top, because at the moment your code will run continously until Excel crashes. A `Worksheet_Change()` event will run when anything changes unless you tell it to only run in certain cases, in your case if a new number goes into column D or E. You need to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot and let me know what error you get:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Only run if something changes in column D or E
    If Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 5 Then

        'Turn off any events so that we don't encounter recursion
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'This will help readability a bit
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim A As Integer
        Dim i As Long

        'This needs to be removed - it's irrelevant as i is used as an iterable on the next line
        'i = 5

        For i = 5 To 12

            If sht.Range("D" & i).Value = "" Or sht.Range("D" & i).Value = 0 Then
                'What's the point of using a variable here?
                A = sht.Range("E" & i).Value - sht.Range("C" & i).Value
                sht.Range("F" & i).Value = A
            Else
                'Order of operations - is that important here?
                'Are we certain these fields are numeric?
                sht.Range("F" & i).Value = sht.Range("D" & i).Value * sht.Range("B" & i).Value _
                + sht.Range("E" & i).Value - sht.Range("C" & i).Value
            End If

        Next i

        'Turn it back on once we're done
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```